# htaccess rewrite and php foreach dont work

Tags: php, .htaccess, foreach

i have this code in php file where getcat() get data frome my sqle and creat links:

```
$categories = getCat() ;
foreach($categories as $cat) {
    echo'<li><a href="category/'.$cat['ID'] .'">' .$cat['Name'].'</a></li>';
}
```

but when i add rewrite the link change to

```
<a href="category/category'/..</a>
```

.htaccess:

```
# Turn Rewrite Engin on
RewriteEngine on

#Rewrite for categories.php?pageid=xxx
RewriteRule ^category/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) categories.php?pageid=$1 [NC,L]
```

i dont know why there is two category

Comment: `why there is two category`, where are there 2 `category`s?

Comment: you realize that `href="category/..."` is  relative to the current path? eg `/music/category` if you were already at `/music`

Answer (score 0):

If you were already at `/category` ie. that's whats displayed in the browser address bar, then clicking a link to `category/...` would navigate you to `/category/category/...`  since `href="category/..."` is a relative path.

You can solve this by placing a `/` in front  `<a href="/category/...">link</a>`

Dont forget to add the `/` in `.htaccess` too

`RewriteRule ^/category/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) categories.php?pageid=$1 [NC,L]`

Comment: My mind may be slipping, but don't you need a $ to end the evaluation or does a space suffice? ex: ^/category/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ categories...

Comment: This links in navbar when ido this it get back on url and ruin it all